# How to use a sizeof with an integer array to avoid "Array does not have a predefined size [...] is a variable and used like a type"

Tags: c#, arrays, sizeof

Here is the program I am trying to execute:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] a = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
            int[] b = new int[4] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
            int v = 42;
            Console.WriteLine("Does the pair exist?" + sumOfTwo(a, b, v));
        }
```

I am trying to find out if there is a pair of elements from each of the arrays to get the result equals to the integer variable. I am a novice so please excuse.

```
public static bool sumOfTwo(int[] a, int[] b, int v)
{
    bool result = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(b); j++)
        {
            if (a[i] + b[j] == v)
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

and at the end I see this error that:

> Error CS0233  'a' does not have a predefined size, therefore sizeof can
>   only be used in an unsafe context (consider using
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf)
>
> Error CS0118  'a' is a variable but is used like a
>   type  SumofTwo    c:\users\kvsrk\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\RandomCodeFightPrograms\SumofTwo\Program.cs

same goes for the array b.

Please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yc1w.jpg)

Comment: What made you think you had to use [`sizeof()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx), which returns _"the size in bytes for an unmanaged type"_?

Comment: ah. "a.length" is what i was looking for. thanks!